# How to use apostrophe in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This value is in a column in a table:

```
 '962091','962092','962093'
```

I try to use this in a `where`. First I declare a variable:

```
DECLARE @KPLnr varchar(100)

SET @KPLnr =  CONVERT(nvarchar(max), dbo.UF_GetOption('FastecKPL')) /* here I get the values in */
```

If I select, I get the correct values of `@KPLnr: '962091', '962092','962093'`, but if I try to use it in a where statement, it seems like the value is set wrong.

I get 0 results, but if I set it manually with:

```
WHERE c.kpl IN ('962091', '962092','962093')
```

I got 414 results.

So why is `WHERE c.kpl IN ('962091', '962092', '962093')` not equal to 
`WHERE c.kpl IN (@KPLnr)` in my code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterize-an-sql-in-clause

Answer (score 0):

When an apostrophe is stored in a text column, you need to *escape* it by adding an extra apostrophe:

```
WHERE c.kpl IN ('962091'', ''962092'',''962093')
```